# Reading an excel data sheet and grabbing cell values to replace fields in a Word doc

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

What I want to do is to read the excel data sheet, and take those cells and replace it into a word doc. So far I am able to read the values but I am not sure how I can grab those values stored into the cell. Here is the code I have written so far:

```
    private static void getStudents()
    {
        string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "StudentInfo.xlsx");
        var dt = ExcelHelper.ReadExcelSheet(fileName,true);
        List<Students> sList = new List<Students>();

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                if (dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[j] != null && dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString().Trim().Length>0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[j]);

                }
            }
        }

        //using (var outputDocument = new TemplateProcessor("cover.docx").SetRemoveContentControls(true))
        //{
        //    outputDocument.FillContent(valuesToFill);
        //    outputDocument.SaveChanges();
        //}


    }
```

ExcelHelper code is down below its from the class. This function is what reads the table. There is also a GetCell function that would be useful but I am not quite sure how to use it.

```
public static DataTable ReadExcelSheet(string fname, bool firstRowIsHeader)
        {
            List<string> Headers = new List<string>();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fname, false))
            {
                //Read the first Sheets 
                Sheet sheet = doc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets.GetFirstChild<Sheet>();
                Worksheet worksheet = (doc.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id.Value) as WorksheetPart).Worksheet;
                IEnumerable<Row> rows = worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>().Descendants<Row>();
                int counter = 0;
                foreach (Row row in rows)
                {
                    counter = counter + 1;
                    //Read the first row as header
                    if (counter == 1)
                    {
                        var j = 1;
                        foreach (Cell cell in row.Descendants<Cell>())
                        {
                            var colunmName = firstRowIsHeader ? GetCellValue(doc, cell) : "Field" + j++;
                            Console.WriteLine(colunmName);
                            Headers.Add(colunmName);
                            dt.Columns.Add(colunmName);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dt.Rows.Add();
                        int i = 0;
                        foreach (Cell cell in row.Descendants<Cell>())
                        {
                            dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = GetCellValue(doc, cell);
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            return dt;
        }

        public static string GetCellValue(SpreadsheetDocument doc, Cell cell)
        {
            if (cell.CellValue != null)
            {
                string value = cell.CellValue.InnerText;
                if (cell.DataType != null && cell.DataType.Value == CellValues.SharedString)
                {
                    return doc.WorkbookPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.ChildElements.GetItem(int.Parse(value)).InnerText;
                }
                return value;
            } else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: That certainly doesn't look like OpenXML code.  What's `ExcelHelper`?  Is `dt` a `DataTable`?  If not, what type is it?

Comment: dt is a data table. ExcelHelper is from a class that I found online that I used to read the table. The code from ExcelHelper has just been added above.

Comment: This looks like java. Is it?

If you're not wedded to java (or C++ if that's what it is) then you might like to try one of these projects: https://github.com/search?q=xls